# Order confirmation receiving twice in magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2.2.6

I am facing same issue in Magento2, After the order gets confirmation we receiving the order confirmation mail twice. We using External plugin JccPaymentGateway , by using that plugin if we do order it sends one mail. But if we select inbuilt magento2 payment option like (Cash on Delivery, Cheque) option sends order confirmation mail twice.

Magento Version : 2.2.6

If you know the solution please reply as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Some third-party modules disabled default order mail due to some customization before order placed event and send customized order success mail programmatically.

So first of all check events used in third-party modules and check code of disabled sending order mail and comment it. It should look like:

```
$this->writer->save('sales_email/order/enabled', 0);
```

If this third-party module sends it's customized order success mail then disable default order success mail from:

> Admin->Stores->Configuration->Sales->Sales Emails->Order->Enabled  => No

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue solved for you? If so, how did you solve it?
I am facing the same issue in Magento 2.4.3. I am using "Check/money order" payment method as default magento payment method and 2 other 3rd party payment methods and I am using default magento email templates. The sales order email works as expected for 3rd party payment modules, but only for "Check/money order" payment customer receiving the order email twice. please let me know the solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.